# EntityManager persist() not saving anything to database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

My entityManager persist() gets id from sequence and puts it to my Image object but the Image object itself is not showing up in the database. EntityManager.flush() gives an error so I can't commit this way. Here is my code.

```
@Repository
public class ImageDaoImpl extends BaseDao implements ImageDao {

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
@Transactional
public void create(Image image) {       
    JpaTemplate jpaTemplate = getJpaTemplate(entityManager);
    jpaTemplate.persist(image);
}
```

```
@Repository
public class BaseDao {

private JpaTemplate jpaTemplate;


public JpaTemplate getJpaTemplate(EntityManager entityManager){
    if(jpaTemplate == null)
        jpaTemplate = new JpaTemplate(entityManager);
    return jpaTemplate;
}
```

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
       p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
       <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="sample"></property>
    </bean>



    <!-- DataSource Setup -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/imageCapture" />
        <property name="username" value="myusername" />
        <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: which JPA / spring version you are using ?

Comment: I'm interested in JPA version.. get rid of JpaTemplate.. will not solve your issue but will be good

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087848/when-does-the-jpa-set-a-generatedvalue-id

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This generally happens when Transaction in not applied.. I doubt @Transactional interceptor is not intercepting properly.

Comment: One more thing to check: Be sure, `@Transactional` annotation is from package `org.springframework.transaction.annotation`, not `javax.transaction` - the second one wasn't working in my case.

Comment: @Gondy you sir, have just put an end to my 2 hour long misery. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Gondy Spring also added support for javax.transaction.Transactional, now one could use that too in Spring applications. Just don't mix the two and be consistent about your choice!

Answer (score 31):

`persist()` means "add object to list of managed entries". To save object to data base you must call `flush()` method. But remember you must call in inside the transaction.

//Edit:
Example save method.

```
public void save(T t){
    // begin transaction 
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if (!em.contains(t)) {
        // persist object - add to entity manager
        em.persist(t);
        // flush em - save to DB
        em.flush();
    }
    // commit transaction at all
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

This is not the best that you can make, but good enough.

Comment: flush()  is called before a commit either way.

Comment: Added entityManager.flush() and got javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Comment: one more. JpaTemplate is just facade for javax.persistance.EntityManager.

Comment: I also have the same problem. But mine is a container managed entitymanager, so I am unable to call `getTransaction()` method. How could I solve it?

Comment: `To save object to data base you must call flush() method.` - not really.. Better to say "you must commit" I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Check EntityManager object is not getting created twice. In my case I was initialize EntityManager object in one method and mistakenly calling that method twice during opening transaction and persisting data.

Incorrect code:

```
EntityTrasaction transaction = getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
getEntityManager().persist(customer); // This line is calling another object of EntityManager
transaction.commit();
```

Correct code:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
em.persist(customer);
transaction.commit();

public EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("punit");
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your server logs. Are you creating new `EntityManger`? and have not begun the transaction. I think, Where you have begun that is another `EntityManager` object.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` . Here in `<context:component-scan base-package="pass"/>` pass should equal to package where your controllers are

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in when running test cases with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`

I solved it by 
wrapping the test function with

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

// in your test funciton 
// Declare a transaction programmatically to be able to rollback.
DefaultTransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
transactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
TransactionStatus transaction = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);

try {
    // here test of Dao goes
} finally {
    transactionManager.rollback(transaction);
}
```

hope this helps you